# Create Color Ramp Node in Compositing Section Blender Through Script Python

Tags: python

I have tried:

```
colorramp = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeColorRamp")
```

That doesn't work, what is the correct script to create **Color Ramp Node** ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! You should provide more information on the context of your problem: library used, problem encountered, what you have tried so far... You should also include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At this point I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: Please don't YELL AT US.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn on Python Tooltips, hovering over the Add > Converter > Color Ramp option shows

```
bpy.ops.node.add_node(type="CompositorNodeValToRGB", ...)
```

(at least on Blender 2.82).